# Creating React components inside lodash forOwn

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, lodash

Have a React functional component that accepts timestamp, email and chatTxt as props

```
function UserChat({timestamp,email,chatTxt}) {
    return (
      .....
    )
}
```

Need a collection of above react component created from a collection of objects of the form

```
timestamp: {email: chatText}
```

by using lodash , *forOwn*

```
forOwn(props.chatObj, (value,timestamp) => 
        forOwn(value, (chatTxt,email) => {
            
        })
  })
```

Since Lodash forOwn only return the object iterated itself, how can this be done?

Comment: Please show the structure of `chatObj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to render the list of UserChat component, you'll need an array, so use `_.map()` instead of `_.forOwn()`.

When iterating an object with `_.map()`, the 2nd param passed to the iteratee (the called function) is the key (`timestamp`). No need to iterate the `value`, just spread it on the component:

```
_.map(props.chatObj, (value, timestamp) => (
  <UserChat {...value} timestamp={timestamp} key={timestamp} />
))
```

With vanilla JS use `Object.entries()` to pairs of [key, value], and then use `Array.map()` and destructuring to get the `timestamp` and other values:

```
Object.entries(props.chatObj).map(([timestamp, value]) => (
  <UserChat {...value} timestamp={timestamp} key={timestamp} />
))
```